# Is Lutz's Programming Python outdated?

Tags: python, python-3.x, resources

I'm considering tackling Mark Lutz's Programming Python, 4th edition book released in 2011 but I'm afraid it can be a little outdated compared to today's Python programming standards.

The book mostly covers three domains where Python can be used: Systems programming, GUI and internet programming and it uses Python 3.2. I was planning to use the book not as a resource to learn about theses topics but to learn about software development using in Python - that is, how to better write and structure the code, etc. Do you think it's worth it, or are there probably better resources out there? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, Mark himself wrote a [huge rant](https://learning-python.com/python-changes-2014-plus.html) about Python's changes in the last ten years and how much he hates them, so maybe have a look at that and judge for yourself.